# Print a doc file using java

Tags: java, printing, doc

I want to print a doc file using java. How can i do it without any 3rd party API.

As far as i know, you have to render the doc file as image and then pass it to the printer. Is there any way to render the doc file in image and then print it?

Comment: "How can i do it without any 3rd party API" can we know why you don't want to use other libraries? They ware made by some good people so others wouldn't have to spend their time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for your reply. I wished to do it cause i wanted to learn how it works. Anyway, if there is no other way, using API wont hurt. In that case, what would you recommend?

Comment: Try apache poi, its a very simple and robust Microsoft document handler
http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have to print any documents yet using Java so can't recommend any particular library but I would start searching on some Apache libraries. Anyway general idea is to prefer already created solutions since they will have better support so potential errors will be couched and corrected faster simply because more people are involved.

Answer (score 4):

You need not convert the document to an image. If you are using Java 6+, you can try:

```
File file = new File("C:\\document.doc");
Desktop.getDesktop().print(file);
```

The method [**`print`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#print-java.io.File-) in the class [**`java.awt.Desktop`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html):

> Prints a file with the native desktop printing facility, using the associated application's print command.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Vargas. I already knew about this class. This class is not robust at all, i can't manipulate the printing data with it. It just loads the system print dialogue.